# Kafka consumer , able process tons of messages

Tags: performance, consumer, apache-kafka

In general case Kafka consumer could be anything, that connects to Kafka and gets messages.

I'm interested in known Kafka consumers for several purposes:

1) process messages and save result in DB(Oracle)

2) process messages and save result in files

What established Kafka consumers can you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Camus Consumer](https://github.com/linkedin/camus) for Kakfa->HDFS. It is a mapreduce job that does distributed data loads out of Kafka.